# Clearing input from form triggers input validation error

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to have the input fields of my form clear when a user clicks submit. There are a lot of stack overflow questions around this topic but they all have confusing, and conflicting answers.

The HTML of my form:

```
<form name="form.myform" validate>
      <div style="margin-top:25px">
       <div style="padding:10px"  class="row my-input-divs">
          <div class="col-9"><input name='comment' id='comment' ng-model="admin.reply" placeholder=" (Type here to send message to guest) " style="height:50px;background-color:#EFF3F6;width:100%" required style="" type="text"></div>
          <div class="col-3"> <input ng-click="sendreply(admin.reply, data.conversation[0].originator,data.conversation[0].property_id)" class="my-btn" required style="width:100%;margin-top:7px" value="Send Reply" type="submit" /></div>
       </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Within the success function when the form is submitted I have:

```
      $('#comment').val('');
      $scope.form.myform.$setPristine();
      $scope.form.myform.$setUntouched();
```

I do add the form to the controller with `$scope.form = {};` and the `setPristine` and `setUntouched` seem to be working.

This code does clear the html of in input field when the user hits submit; however, it then displays the error `Please fill out this field` upon being cleared.

Additionally, The code still appears bound to the model. If the user clicks submit a second time after their input has been cleared from the HTML it will submit the original input a second time.

Does anyone know the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Try changing `type="submit"` to `type="button"`. `type="submit"` will cause the form to be validated.

Comment: why you used $('#comment').val(''); to clear the model? Try setting admin.reply to '' directly